# HttpRuntime.Cache - Get CreationTime of Entry

Tags: c#, reflection, httpruntime.cache

I have a little CMS which is working with Razor Views which get rendered from a database. Everything is working fine until you change one of the pages.

As the page is assigned to a virtual path, MVC or the `RazorViewEngine` will cache the view, which makes total sense.

How ever, if someone makes a change i would like to clear the cache for this particular view. Also i would like to clear the cache when before rendering the page. So my idea was to add a "Updated" `DateTime` information to my View in the database (this field is there anyway as it is   one of our standard fields in our tables) and then compare this Date with the CreateTime of the Entry in `HttpRuntime.Cache`. I can see that there is a CreationTime with VisualStudio but I am not that experienced with Reflection to get to this value.

Also, as I have heard, Reflection isn't very fast and if I have to do it everytime a page gets rendered it would slow down the page.

So my question, can 1. someone help me to get the CreationTime from a `HttpRuntime.Cache` entry with Reflection or does 2. someone know a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in the wrong place of the MVC Framework, what i was after is the Cache of the `VirtualPathProvider`, I have found the methods which I have to overwrite.
For the ones who face the same problem.

- `GetCacheDependency`
- `GetFileHash`